# SWT no longer seems present in PDE enviorment

Tags: swt, eclipse-pde

I updated my version of Eclipse to platform version 4.11.0. I am no encountering the following error:

```
TDescription    Resource    Path    Location    Type
```

The method getNameFromNodeNumber(String) is undefined for the type IpNameLookupReader   ViewController.java /com.rci.edge.ttnt_view_controller/src/com/rci/edge/ttnt_view_controller/impl   line 2064   Java Problem

The method setTexture(gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.GpuResourceCache, com.jogamp.opengl.util.texture.Texture) in the type TextureTile is not applicable for the arguments (gov.nasa.worldwind.cache.GpuResourceCache, com.sun.opengl.util.texture.Texture)   AbstractQuadKeyLayer.java   /com.rci.edge.worldwind.adapter/src/com/rci/edge/worldwind/layers/virtualearth/impl line 373    Java Problem

The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter. Fix the build path then try building this project com.rci.ttm.test.ui.views.configurationinspector        Unknown Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files ConfigurationInspectorView.java /com.rci.ttm.test.ui.views.configurationinspector/src/com/rci/ttm/test/ui/views/configurationinspector  line 1  Java Problem
The type org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files   TtntRouteTableView.java /com.rci.ttm.ui.views.ttntroutetable/src/com/rci/ttm/ui/views/ttntroutetable    line 1  Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  PacketStatsView.java    /com.rci.ttm.ui.views.packetstats/src/com/rci/ttm/ui/views/packetstats  line 1  Java Problem
The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  RcnmpLatencyView.java   /com.rci.ttm.isr.ui.views.rcnmplatency/src/com/rci/ttm/isr/ui/views/rcnmplatency    line 1  Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  SNRView.java    /com.rci.ttm.ui.views.snr/src/com/rci/ttm/ui/views/snr  line 1  Java Problem
The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  TopReceiversView.java   /com.rci.ttm.isr.ui.views.topreceivers/src/com/rci/ttm/isr/ui/views/topreceivers    line 1  Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  TopTalkersView.java /com.rci.ttm.isr.ui.views.toptalkers/src/com/rci/ttm/isr/ui/views/toptalkers    line 1  Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  TsharkOutputView.java   /com.rci.ttm.ui.views.wiresharkoutput/src/com/rci/ttm/ui/views/wiresharkoutput  line 1  Java Problem

The type org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  BasicLoginDialog.java   /com.rci.edge.trilead_SSH_service/src/com/rci/edge/trilead_SSH_service/impl line 1  Java Problem

I have tried including the org.eclipse.swt as a required plugin

my current eclispe configuration is as follows:
  Buildship: Eclipse Plug-ins for Gradle    3.0.1.v20181217-1554    org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group Eclipse Buildship
  EclEmma Java Code Coverage    3.1.2.201903112331  org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group   Eclipse EclEmma
  Eclipse IDE for Java Developers   4.11.0.20190314-1200    epp.package.java    Eclipse Packaging Project
  Eclipse Java Development Tools    3.17.0.v20190307-0500   org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse Platform  4.11.0.v20190307-0500   org.eclipse.platform.feature.group  Eclipse.org
  Eclipse RCP   4.11.0.v20190307-0500   org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group   Eclipse.org
  Eclipse XML Editors and Tools 3.13.0.v201903050402    org.eclipse.wst.xml_ui.feature.feature.group    Eclipse Web Tools Platform
  Git integration for Eclipse   5.3.0.201903130848-r    org.eclipse.egit.feature.group  Eclipse EGit
  Git integration for Eclipse - Task focused interface  5.3.0.201903130848-r    org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse EGit
  Java implementation of Git    5.3.0.201903130848-r    org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group  Eclipse JGit
  m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse (includes Incubating components)  1.11.0.20190220-2119    org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  m2e - slf4j over logback logging (Optional)   1.11.0.20190220-2119    org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group   Eclipse.org - m2e
  Marketplace Client    1.7.5.v20190313-2005    org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group   Eclipse Marketplace Client
  Mylyn Builds Connector: Hudson/Jenkins    1.16.0.v20180403-2055   org.eclipse.mylyn.hudson.feature.group  Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Eclipse IDE  3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.ide_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Context Connector: Java Development 3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.java_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task List   3.24.2.v20180905-0003   org.eclipse.mylyn_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Task-Focused Interface  3.24.2.v20180905-0014   org.eclipse.mylyn.context_feature.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Tasks Connector: Bugzilla   3.24.2.v20180905-0003   org.eclipse.mylyn.bugzilla_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn Versions Connector: Git 1.16.0.v20170629-1738   org.eclipse.mylyn.git.feature.group Eclipse Mylyn
  Mylyn WikiText    3.0.25.201806201740 org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group    Eclipse Mylyn
  Oomph Setup   1.13.0.v20190410-1549   org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group   Eclipse Oomph Project
  Tip of the Day UI Feature 0.2.400.v20190218-1605  org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group  Eclipse.org

Comment: Eclipse would not work at all if SWT was missing. Is the `swr` in the package name actually what you have or a typo? What are you using as your Target Platform?

Comment: Sorry yes that is a typo. 
The type org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Button cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files  is just one of SWT errors I'm currently receiving.

Comment: What are the other errors that you're seeing? If you're seeing a larger set of error messages/stack traces, please update your question to include all of them.

Comment: Updated description to show a sampling of the errors being received.

Comment: I had the same program when opening a workspace previously used on Windows, in Linux. I had to change some properties in the Preferences page called Target Platform  from a win32 to linux platform.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some bundle used to re-export the org.eclipse.swt and stopped to do that in 4.11.0
The fastest solution is:

1) Ensure that your target platform has the org.eclipse.swt bundle enabled, use 
*Window -> Preferences -> Plug-in Development -> Target Platform*

2) Ensure that your target platform has an enabled org.eclipse.swt.* fragment matching your "platform", like "org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64"

3) Add "org.eclipse.swt" to the list of required bundles for your bundle.

The good rule is to re-export the dependency if it is a part of the bundle API